# Exported layout cuts through axis label

Tags: qgis-3, export, layouts

Exporting a map layout (both as pdf and image) results in the uppermost y-axis label being partly cut off. It looks like the upper layout boundary is set by the map rather than the label. Any way to fix this? 
[image: y-axis label partly cut off when exporting layout]

Comment: I added extra space around the layout by increasing the margin size (via **Resize Layout to Content**), but this didn't fix it.

Comment: Is the label cut off in the print layout, or only in the exported image/pdf?

Comment: Only in the exported files

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue, which makes it difficult to troubleshoot. The cutoff happens at about the same place on the page that the content would be cut off if you tried to print it on paper. QGIS doesn't detect your printer's printable area margins, so I'm not sure how that would be happening. Maybe that's just a coincidence.

Comment: Thats just coincidence I think... I increased the top margin to a couple of centimetres with the same result. Very strange that you couldn't reproduce this. I am going to make an entirely new layout and see if this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs when decreasing the frame width. Apparently, the upper map boundary is set by the frame. With the preset width of [2mm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twa8f.png), the frame extends further up than the label. When decreasing the width to [1mm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r0Zs.png) it doesn’t and the label is cut off. The issue even occurs when [removing the frame entirely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z46Pl.png).
Seems like this is an issue that should be fixed in a future version of QGis.